# Not able to use flat ui with meteor

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, meteor, flat, flatui

I have downloaded flat-ui from official website. Then I copy pased `dist` folder in root directory of the application. 
I have created basic meteor app using `meteor create app_name`
I am trying to implement the login form given on demo page of flat-ui.

http://designmodo.github.io/Flat-UI/
Login page is at the end of the page.

As far as know meteor can iterate through all the folder in the root directory and add css files.(correct me if I am wrong). Also I get error like

```html
W20150210-01:58:23.516(5.5)? (STDERR)         
W20150210-01:58:23.519(5.5)? (STDERR) /home/ajinkya/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.38.ieqxkv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
W20150210-01:58:23.519(5.5)? (STDERR)       throw(ex);
W20150210-01:58:23.520(5.5)? (STDERR)             ^
W20150210-01:58:23.520(5.5)? (STDERR) ReferenceError: document is not defined
W20150210-01:58:23.521(5.5)? (STDERR)     at app/dist/js/vendor/html5shiv.js:322:9
W20150210-01:58:23.521(5.5)? (STDERR)     at app/dist/js/vendor/html5shiv.js:324:3
W20150210-01:58:23.521(5.5)? (STDERR)     at /home/ajinkya/projects/umang/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:175:10
W20150210-01:58:23.522(5.5)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20150210-01:58:23.522(5.5)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/home/ajinkya/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.38.ieqxkv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20150210-01:58:23.522(5.5)? (STDERR)     at /home/ajinkya/projects/umang/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:86:5
=> Exited with code: 8
```

So I tried removing `js` folder. After that error went but when I tried that login form example there was no icons in input box.

Please help me with this. I think its maybe folder structure that is causing the issue.

Comment: You have to put all this into client/, document isn't defined on server side and that's what meteor assumes when you put files into root directory

Comment: Or check https://atmospherejs.com/sahina/flatui

Comment: Always check [Atmosphere](http://atmospherejs.com) first.